# Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH Django app deployment on vercel error

Tags: python, django, vercel, rust-cargo

Error on vercel deployment log.

```
Error: Command failed: pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      
      Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
      This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
      the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/
      
      Checking for Rust toolchain....
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

Error on vercel deployment Log

```
BUILD_FAILED: Command failed: pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt  error: subprocess-exited-with-error    × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.  │ exit code: 1  ╰─> [6 lines of output]            Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.      This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through      the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/            Checking for Rust toolchain....      [end of output]    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.error: metadata-generation-failed× Encountered error while generating package metadata.╰─> See above for output.note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.hint: See above for details.Collecting anyio==3.6.2  Downloading anyio-3.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (80 kB)     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 80.6/80.6 kB 14.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00Collec
```

**Requirement.txt**
used for deployemnt on vercel.

```
anyio==3.6.2
argon2-cffi==21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
asgiref==3.6.0
asttokens==2.1.0
attrs==22.1.0
backcall==0.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
bleach==5.0.1
cffi==1.15.1
cmake==3.24.3
colorama==0.4.6
contourpy==1.0.6
cycler==0.11.0
debugpy==1.6.3
decorator==5.1.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
Django==4.1.7
django-cors-headers==3.14.0
django-environ==0.10.0
dlib==19.24.0
entrypoints==0.4
executing==1.2.0
fastjsonschema==2.16.2
fonttools==4.38.0
idna==3.4
ipykernel==6.17.1
ipython==8.6.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==8.0.2
jedi==0.18.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
joblib==1.2.0
jsonschema==4.17.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-console==6.4.4
jupyter-server==1.23.3
jupyter_client==7.4.7
jupyter_core==5.0.0
jupyterlab-pygments==0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets==3.0.3
kiwisolver==1.4.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
matplotlib==3.6.2
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
mistune==2.0.4
nbclassic==0.4.8
nbclient==0.7.0
nbconvert==7.2.5
nbformat==5.7.0
nest-asyncio==1.5.6
notebook==6.5.2
notebook_shim==0.2.2
numpy==1.23.5
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.5.2
pandocfilters==1.5.0
parso==0.8.3
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==9.3.0
platformdirs==2.5.4
prometheus-client==0.15.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.33
psutil==5.9.4
pure-eval==0.2.2
pycparser==2.21
Pygments==2.13.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
pyrsistent==0.19.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.6
pypiwin32==223
pywinpty==2.0.9
pyzmq==24.0.1
qtconsole==5.4.0
QtPy==2.3.0
scikit-learn==1.2.1
scipy==1.9.3
Send2Trash==1.8.0
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
sqlparse==0.4.3
stack-data==0.6.1
terminado==0.17.0
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
tinycss2==1.2.1
tornado==6.2
traitlets==5.5.0
tzdata==2022.7
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==1.4.2
widgetsnbextension==4.0.3
```

Deploying an api written in Django. It is using machine learning model to predict and send response to the api.
But getting an error when deploying it on vercel as described above.
I am using python version 3.9.
Requirement.txt file is also attached.

Comment: _"... This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/ ..."_ Did you try installing it as the error message suggests?

Comment: can you suggest a way to install that on vercel when deploying.

Comment: Facing same issue. Any solution for this?

Comment: @JerryChong where are you trying to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem on my Windows machine while trying to install the `transformers` library. I installed Cargo through this link - https://rustup.rs/.

After downloading the `rustup-init.exe` file from the above link, follow the onscreen instructions to install Cargo. The setup says it will Cargo to `PATH`, but in my case, it did NOT. So, make sure you add `.cargo\bin` to both ***System variables*** `PATH` and the '***User Variables***' `PATH`. Only then it worked for me.